# How to see the source code of google app script project?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I would like to know in any means, if we could see the source code of an App script Project provided with the Web app URL that ends with "/exec" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is one of your script then simply replace "/exec" with "/edit"

Comment: No the point is, I would like to know if anyother with the link can view my code?

Comment: No, this would be a problem indeed...see Jonathon's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't own or have the script shared with you in Google Drive, it is not possible to see the server side code.

Comment: Even the HTML code looks messy when I used View Source Option in browser. So Is it an advantage or disadvantage?

Comment: The HTML code has been 'cajoled'. This is another security feature. When debugging I sometimes write out the pre-filtered HtmlService output into a variable on the page for inspection in dev tools.