# Is it possible to view the GAS code published as an application from outside?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to publish a project created with Google Apps Script as an application.
I'm planning to make it accessible to anyone so that people who don't have a Google account can use it.
So my question is, is there any way to view the source code of a published application from the outside?
I'm worried about security because the code contains information that I don't want to show to the outside world, such as API keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see the source code of google app script project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154814/how-to-see-the-source-code-of-google-app-script-project)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362359/apps-script-web-app-visible-source-code-library

Comment: No. See the above comments.

Comment: It's what I was looking for. Thanks!